# How does the sum of eigenvalues tell us the eigenvalues?

Tags: representation-theory

In reading "Representation Theory" by William Fulton and Joe Harris, I encountered the following statement, which confuses me. The context is this: $G$ is a finite group, and we are interested in the irreducible representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

"If we know the eighevalues $\{\lambda_i\}$ of an element $g \in G$, then of course we know the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i^k\}$ of $g^k$ for each $k$ as well. We can thus use this redundancy to simplify the data we have to specify. The key observation here is it is enough to give, for example, just the sum of the eigenvalues of each element of $G$, since knowing the sums $\sum\lambda_i^k$ of the $k$th powers of the eigenvalues of a given element $g \in G$ is equivalent to knowing the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$ of $g$ itself."

The two sentences pose no problems for me. However, I do not know why the 3rd sentence is true. How can knowing the sum of the eigenvalues of $g$ tell us the eigenvalues of $g$?

Comment: We can compute the eigenvalues using the sums of their powers using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities)